# How do I use SharedPreferences in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to save and retrieve some application settings in my Xamarin.Android project.

I know that in Android (java), I use the class `SharedPreferences` to store this information, but I do not know how to convert that to Xamarin C#.

When I type "SharedPreferences" into the Xamarin Studio IDE, there is no auto-completion, so I don't know what to use.

---

An initial search of the interwebs took me to a related question, but only contains Android java:

- [Use Shared Preferences in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082199/use-shared-preferences-in-xamarin)

---

So to summarise:

- What is the **Xamarin Android C# equivalent** of Android Java's `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The Xamarin.Android equivalent of `SharedPreferences` is an interface called `ISharedPreferences`.

Use it in the same way, and you will be able to easily port Android code across.

---

For example, to save a true/false `bool` using some `Context` you can do the following:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
editor.PutBoolean ("key_for_my_bool_value", mBool);
// editor.Commit();    // applies changes synchronously on older APIs
editor.Apply();        // applies changes asynchronously on newer APIs
```

Access saved values using:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (mContext);
mBool = prefs.GetBoolean ("key_for_my_bool_value", <default value>);
mInt = prefs.GetInt ("key_for_my_int_value", <default value>);
mString = prefs.GetString ("key_for_my_string_value", <default value>);
```

---

From this sample, you can see that once you know the correct C# interface to use, the rest is easy. There are many Android java examples on how to use `SharedPreferences` for more complex situations, and these can be ported very easily using `ISharedPreferences`.

For more information, read this thread:

- [Android Shared Preference on Xamarin forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4758/android-shared-preference)

Comment: PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences is deprecated

Answer (score 27):

You can use this example for you SharedPreferences in Xamarin.Android

First, you need to use:

```
ISharedPreferences //Interface for accessing and modifying preference data
ISharedPreferencesEditor // Interface used for modifying values in a ISharedPreferences
```

You can create a similar class:

```
public class AppPreferences
{
    private ISharedPreferences mSharedPrefs;
    private ISharedPreferencesEditor mPrefsEditor;
    private Context mContext;

    private static String PREFERENCE_ACCESS_KEY = "PREFERENCE_ACCESS_KEY";
        
    public AppPreferences (Context context)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        mPrefsEditor = mSharedPrefs.Edit ();            
    }

    public void saveAccessKey(string key){
        mPrefsEditor.PutString(PREFERENCE_ACCESS_KEY, key);
        mPrefsEditor.Commit();
    }

    public string getAccessKey(){
        return mSharedPrefs.GetString(PREFERENCE_ACCESS_KEY, "");
    }
}
```

From the Activity:

```
Context mContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
AppPreferences ap = new AppPreferences (mContext);
```

If you want to save some value:

```
string key = "123123";
ap.saveAccessKey (key);
```

If you want to get the value:

```
string key = ap.getAccessKey();
```

Comment: Using this worked for me. Just wondering, in your code there is no dispose. So I thought to implement a dispose method calling it after I was done in the activity. But then I noticed that if I used the class in a service where I disposed it, this code crashed saying there was no instance.  At the moment, I commented out the dispose, but winder if the memory will have a leak?

Comment: PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences is deprecated

Answer (score 8):

I had trouble using PreferenceManager as the example shows. I added this code at the top and now I'm good using it.

```
using Android.Preferences;
```

Plus to get the preferences you have to add the default value as a second parameter or it will not compile

```
mInt = prefs.GetInt ("key_for_my_int_value", defaultInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still dont know or not, but make sure you **Dispose** your variables if they are inside a function:

```
prefs.Dispose();
prefEditor.Dispose();
```

I had a crash/freeze on my app over some time because of not disposing the memory whenever it is not needed anymore.