# c# / Xamarin: Getting a class name instead of instance of class

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to save a variable to persistent storage (as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/application-class/)) but the complier doesn't recognise the 'Current' member of 'Application' class. I'm trying this:

```
Application.Current.Properties["id"] = id;
```

but VS2015 assumes that 'application' is an instance of the 'Application' class, not the class itself. (the error given is: 'application' does not contain a definition for 'Current').

The instance is defined in a  library module:

```
public Application Application { get; }
```

I've tried GetType() and MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() without success. Sorry if this is basic c# knowledge that I've forgotten.

Comment: are you using Forms, or is this just an Android project?  The link you're using is for Forms, but your replies below make it sound like this is an Android project.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is an Android project. I did search for 'Xamarin Android persistent storage' but didn't notice that the info that came up was about forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fully qualified type name including the namespace where the class is declared in:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties["id"] = id;
```

Comment: Better, thanks, but still not there. 'Android.App.Application.Current.Properties["id"] = id' : now 'Application' is recognised as a class , but still no definition for 'Current'. Looks the latest update to Xamarin (which I just installed) doesn't have this definition, I can't find it in the metadata for 'Android.App'

Comment: It's only available in projects that use Xamarin Forms. You don't use Xamarin Forms it seems.

Comment: Do you only want to target android? If yes, you can use the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668509/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-in-xamarin-android

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, this is an Android project. I did a search for 'Xamarin Android persistent storage' but didn't notice that the info that came up was about forms. 'SharedPreferences' works fine; I only want to store one integer.