# Display a view only once on application first run

Tags: android, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences

I'm working on Xamarin Android and I need to show a images carousel when application start.

I have seen some implementations with Java Shared Preferences, but I don't know how to do this with Xamarin. Could you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you make any research at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668509/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-in-xamarin-android

Comment: I don't know why didn't see this article before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access shared prefs on Xamarin:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
```

Then to check for a "firstRun" using shared preferences:

```
            if (prefs.GetBoolean ("firstRun", true)) {
                LaunchImagesCarousel ();
                prefs.Edit ().PutBoolean ("firstRun", false).Commit ();
            } else {
               // something else
            }
```

I use the same approach to display a tutorial of carousel images if its user's first time opening the app.

If this is deemed redundant, unnecessary and/or likely answered elsewhere, please do remove it.

Answer (score 0):

With Xamarin Forms you can do `VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchEver`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking