# Xamarin: Application.Current.Propertties - no Definition

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

While trying to get my first Xamarin app running I want to save data. This seems to be done e.g. with

```
Application.Current.Properties["id"] = id;
```

My problem is that Visual Studio does not "recognize" the Current - and Intellisense does not offer it to me.

I imported

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
```

Whole Code in protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle):

```
btnSaveLogin.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                Application.Current.Properties["id"] = id;
            };
```

What Am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application.Current.Properties applies to Xamarin.Forms, not Xamarin.Android.  In Xamarin Android you can achieve a similar result by using [SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668509/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-in-xamarin-android).