# How accessing xamarin forms properties from android GcmService

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I  can store data using Application.Current.Properties [key]

But how how can I read this data from Android when a remote notification arrives ?

If the aplication is closed and there is no "current" Xamarin Form Aplication how can I read/write this data?

```
 [Service]
public class GcmService : GcmServiceBase
{
    public static string RegistrationID { get; private set; }

    public GcmService()
        : base(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.SENDER_IDS) { }

    protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationId)
    {
        Log.Verbose("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Registered: " + registrationId);
        RegistrationID = registrationId;
    }

    protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        var msg = new StringBuilder();

        if (intent != null && intent.Extras != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
                msg.AppendLine(key + "=" + intent.Extras.Get(key).ToString());
        }



        string textoNotificacion = intent.Extras.GetString("gcm.notification.body");
        var nombre = "Alumno - ";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textoNotificacion))
        {
            //***************************************** //
            var idEstatus = "0";
            var textoEstatus = "Cambio de Estatus";

            if (textoNotificacion.Length > 2)
            {
                idEstatus = textoNotificacion.Substring(0, 1);
                textoEstatus = textoNotificacion.Substring(1);
            }


            try
            {

                var app = App.Current;                  

                if (app == null)
                {
                    Read and Save data in xamarin form properties here!!!

                }
                else
                {
                    var mp = (MainPage)app.MainPage;
                    nombre = mp.getNombre() + " - ";
                    mp.actualizarEstatus(idEstatus, textoEstatus);
                }





            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                createNotification("Aplication ",e.Message);
            }




            createNotification("Aplication ",   nombre +textoEstatus);
            return;
        }

        createNotification("Unknown message details", msg.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: This GcmService, as the name suggests, is a service, and the OnMessage method will be executed regardless the application state... Thinking this way the question is making no sense... Are you considering about this service behavior?

Comment: No, my question is very clear. How can I access the data in Xamarin Form Properties. I say there is no current App so obviosly thats not the way. My question is about another way yo access that data. Maybe a path file or another library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant read data from  `Application.Current.Properties [key]` when your App is closed, instead, you can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store data. `SharePreferences` is a mechanism in Android for storing some simple configuration information, using the Map data structure to store data, stored as `key-value` pairs, and storing the data in the `XML` format.

The created storage file is saved under the `/data/data/<package name>/shares_prefs` folder. For this reason data in `SharedPreferences` will be persistent even though user closes the application.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668509/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-in-xamarin-android) is a document about how to use SharePreferences in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: That works only for andriod but not with IOS, having xamarin forms how can access to xamarin form properties?

Comment: I am not familiar  with IOS, you can  open  a new thread to ask the question. : )