# Xamarin.Android save current progress

Tags: c#, android, sql, json, xamarin.android

I've developed a picking app in Xamarin.Android which is used for picking orders in a warehouse. Users of the app open the app on their android scanners and scan barcodes, item quantity and transport unit where they put the scanned item.

Using ***DataAdapter*** I insert SQL data into object lists, e.g. *List< TransportUnit>*, *List< Item>*, *List< Order>*, etc. If the picker close the app on their scanner and login on another scanner they should be able to continue  where they left off. That means all the objects from scanner 1 should load on scanner 2. I used ***Serialization*** to JSON for saving objects to SQL data table, and when user logs in on another device all the objects are deserialized back to lists.

However, sometimes writing the serialized objects to SQL fails and when user restart the app or change scanner they get wrong/outdated objects. So, basically, this is a very inconvenient way of saving app's progress and I would be very thankful if you guide me on a better, more sophisticated way of saving the picking progress.

Comment: On requirements like this i would suggest you use shared preferences rather than SQLite and check for preferences being empty or not for using the same [SharedPrefrences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26668566/7462031)

Comment: @G.hakim what happens when user switch to another device?

Comment: Well then you cannot save it like that then you will have to have an API and a database where you will store user specific data