# Xamarin Forms / Android - Intent Extras is null

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent, extra

i am trying to open image intent (select files from gallery) but need to pass certain id (project / report id) which needs to be processed for intent result.

Whatever i have tried for intent options / flags, putting extra for intent (string) is working, but on result extras are empty always. this is the related code (both in mainactivity):

```
var imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
                    imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
                    imageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
                    imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                    imageIntent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);

                    if (ProjectId != null && ProjectId.ToString().Length > 0) imageIntent.PutExtra("ProjectId", ProjectId.ToString());
                    if (ReportId != null && ReportId.ToString().Length > 0) imageIntent.PutExtra("ReportId", ReportId.ToString());

                    CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.StartActivityForResult(imageIntent, requestCode);
```

and

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        ...

        if (data.Extras != null)
        {
          if (data.GetStringExtra ("ProjectId") != null) int.TryParse(data.GetStringExtra("ProjectId"), out ProjectId);
          if (data.GetStringExtra("ReportId") != null) Guid.TryParse(data.GetStringExtra("ReportId"), out ReportId);
        }
```

data.Extras is null here.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The Activity returning data needs to set these extras, not clear if that happens.

Answer (score 1):

> data.Extras is null

It is correct, there are two Intents.

When you use `StartActivityForResult` to open the `Gallery`, this imageIntent we can called `Intent1`, `Intent1` contains `ProjectId` and `ReportId`. When you select the Image, back to the previous activity, System will generate a new Intent, we can called `Intent2`. `Itent2` just contains you select image information, it not contains `ProjectId` and `ReportId`, So you get null with `data.Extras` in `OnActivityResult`.

If you want to get the `ProjectId` and `ReportId` information in any activity or other classes in android project, you can use `SharedPreferences` to achieve it.

[How do I use SharedPreferences in Xamarin.Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668509/how-do-i-use-sharedpreferences-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: would not like to handle this by SharedPreferences, as requirement here is to avoid issues with gallery / messagingservice (which are leading to incorrect project / report id). any other to handle / achieve that?

Comment: In xamarin forms, you can use `File Handling` or `local  Databases` to store information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: @NormanNor Are there any update for this issue, if above answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue